# How to explain light reduction in Helmert demonstration (Chi square distribution)?

Tags: probability-distributions, chi-squared

I search to understand how Helmert find his second equation (2) in his article that explain Chi Square distribution function.

You can find [Helmert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Robert_Helmert) article from 1876 on [Goettingen University Site](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN599415665_0021) (PDF page = 208) (Book page = 193)

[image]

In this article Helmert write a very important equation that is THE basis of Chi Square function's formula.

I have translated in english what he written in german.

---

If $n = 1$, the probability that $ε_1^m$ is between $σ_m-dε/2$ and $σ_m+dε/2$ is equal to

$$
 φ(σ_m)_1.δ_m=\int_{\sqrt[m]{σ_m-δ_m/2}}^{\sqrt[m]{σ_m+δ_m/2}}ψ(ε)dε
$$

where index 1 has been added to $φ(σ_m)$ expression because $n = 1$.

Since $δ_m$ is supposed to to be a differential, this expression can be written as following form

$$
 φ(σ_m)_1 δ_m=\big(\sqrt[m]{σ_m+δ_m/2}-\sqrt[m]{σ_m-δ_m/2}\big).ψ(\sqrt[m]{σ_m})
$$

Now, supposing that $σ_m$ can never be equal to zero, we obtain, AFTER LIGHT REDUCTION, following equation

$$
 φ(σ_m)_1 δ_m=\frac{ψ(\sqrt[m]{σ_m})}{mσ_m^{(1-\frac{1}{m})}}δ_m
$$

---

QUESTION: What are these LIGHT reduction ?

How is it possible from

$$
 φ(x) δ_m=\big(\sqrt[m]{x+δ_m/2}-\sqrt[m]{x-δ_m/2}\big).ψ(\sqrt[m]{x})
$$

to deduce that

$$
 φ(x)=\frac{ψ(\sqrt[m]{x})}{mx^{(1-\frac{1}{m})}}
$$

Or how it is possible that

$$
 \big(\sqrt[m]{x+δ_m/2}-\sqrt[m]{x-δ_m/2}\big)=\frac{\sqrt[m]{x}}{mx}δ_m
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equality can be explained using Taylor serie for $\sqrt[m]{1+x}$

if -1 < x < 1 then
$$
\sqrt[m]{1 + x} = 1 + \frac{1}{m}x - \frac{(1+m)}{2!\space m^2}x^2 + \frac{(1+m)(1+2m)}{3!\space m^3}x^3\space\space\space\space(1)
$$
$$
\sqrt[m]{1 - x} = 1 - \frac{1}{m}x - \frac{(1+m)}{2!\space m^2}x^2 - \frac{(1+m)(1+2m)}{3!\space m^3}x^3\space\space\space\space(2)
$$

---

The first expression
$$
\sqrt[m]{x+δ_m/2}-\sqrt[m]{x-δ_m/2}
$$
can also be written as
$$
\sqrt[m]{x+x.δ_m/2x}-\sqrt[m]{x-x.δ_m/2x}
$$
putting $x$ in evidence we obtain
$$
\sqrt[m]{x(1+δ_m/2x)}-\sqrt[m]{x(1-δ_m/2x)}
$$
extracting x from $\sqrt[m]{...}$ we obtain
$$
\sqrt[m]{x}.\big(\sqrt[m]{1+δ_m/2x}-\sqrt[m]{1-δ_m/2x}\big)
$$
now considering Taylor serie (1) and (2) and neglecting term greater than $x^2$  because they are insignicant, we obtain
$$
\sqrt[m]{x}\space\big((1+\frac{1}{m}\frac{δ_m}{2x}-\frac{(1+m)}{2!\space m^2}\frac{δ_m^2}{4\space x^2})-(1-\frac{1}{m}\frac{δ_m}{2x}-\frac{(1+m)}{2!\space m^2}\frac{δ_m^2}{4\space x^2})\big)
$$
in resolving expression we obtain
$$
\sqrt[m]{x}\space\big(2.\frac{δ_m}{2mx}\big)
$$
that is equal to
$$
\frac{\sqrt[m]{x}}{mx}δ_m
$$

The tip used by Helmert is to use Taylor series for $\sqrt[m]{1+x}$ and $\sqrt[m]{1-x}$ and to cut terms greater that $x^2$ because they are insignificant.